# Can't connect from mongojs but command line is OK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongojs

I use mongojs to connect my Node.JS to MongoDB.

When I do `mongo easymail -u admin -p PWD --authenticationDatabase=admin` from bash, everything goes right.

But : `mongodb://admin:PWD@localhost:27017/easymail?auto_reconnect=true&authSource=admin` give me

`{ [MongoError: auth failed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'auth failed',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'auth failed',
  code: 18 }`

Where is the problem ?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your password contain a `@` character? If so, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-187

Comment: Nop the only special char in my password is `!`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your entire command, but it looks like it could be an issues with escaping. Try placing your connections string in double quotes like this:

```
mongo "mongodb://admin:PWD@localhost:27017/easymail?auto_reconnect=true&authSource=admin"
```

Comment: Hello, I can't see any double quote... I tried your command : `Error: More than one ':' detected.`

Comment: I minified your command to `mongo localhost:27017/easymail?authSource=admin -u admin -p PWD` to make it working. Same problem 'Auth Failed'. But when I do `mongo localhost:27017/admin -u admin -p PWD` everything is ok...

Comment: It seems that mongoDB ignore the authSource argument from shell or node